# Getting URL and manipulating it with JSON schema references

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, http, jsonschema

I have JSON schema with references. I have to make a http request to get JSON schema with references.Below is my HTTP request call in Javascript.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'http://www.jsonschema.com/src/JSON_schemas/json_1.json', false);  
request.send(null);
if (request.status === 200) {
  return JSON.parse(request.responseText);
}
else
  return {};
```

I get JSON schema as **request** like this.(json_1.json as request.responseText)

```
{
  "$schema" : "http://...",
  "id" : "67",
  "type" : "object",
  "properties": {
    "accountId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "alternateIds": {
       "$ref": "../V1/alternate_ids.json"
     },
     "associations": {
       "$ref": "../V1/associations.json"
     },
     "layers": {
       "type": "array",
       "$ref": "../V1/account_layers.json"
     },
     "transactions": {
       "$ref": "transactions.json",
       "description": "This is an optional field."
     }
  }
}
```

Now how will I make a call to get **"../V1/alternate_ids.json"** JSON file?

basically I should replace URL to `'http://www.jsonschema.com/src/JSON_schemas/json_1.json'` to `'http://www.jsonschema.com/src/V1/alternate_ids.json'` for it to make a correct call.

But how will I achieve this manipulation of URLs programmatically?

Basically the ref is path to file system in remote computer. So I have the base URL and as and when I see ref I should change my URl to get the that referenced file

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below:

```
var basicUrl = "http://www.jsonschema.com/src"
var jsonSchema = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
var jsonProperties = jsonSchema['properties']; 
var alternateIdsRef = jsonProperties['alternateIds']['$ref'];
var truncatedRef = alternateIdsRef.split('..').pop();
var myUrl = basicUrl +  truncatedRef;
console.log(myUrl);
```

Explanation:

JSON object is basically a JavaScript object and then the data could be accessed inside it using the same dot/bracket notation for the JavaScript objects:
  `jsonSchema['properties']`.

`split()` splits (divides) a string into an array of substrings.

`pop()` removes the last element of an array, and returns that element.

Comment: But what if the ref is like this. "$ref" : ../../../V2/common/types.json?

Comment: Everytime the structure of ref is not same. Its specifies the relative path to the files

Comment: Basically the ref is path to file system in remote computer. So I have the base URL and as and when I see ref I should change my URl to get the that referenced file

Comment: Then var splittedRef[] =  alternateIdsRef.split('..') and use for cycle: for (statement 1; statement 2; statement 3) {
    code block to be executed
}